# firebase-ui how to override the title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebaseui

to log in into my React app I'm using firebase with firebaseui.

```
<StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
```

Unfortunately, I can't override the Title (Sign in with email). Any ideas how change the title?

[image]

Comment: Firebaseui-web provides option to change the color, label of buttons etc but there are no options to change what you are asking.